# formatting SSD as ext4 becomes corrupted, superblock

Tags: mount, filesystem, usb3

I want my Pi4b to mount an external ssd (connected by usb3), and have some new drives that came formatted exfat. Since I need symlinks and other advantages of ext4, I change the partition type to 83, and reformat it with mke2fs. without journal, and lazy_itable to reduce wear. I also mount with the discard option. Sound good so far?

After an hour of use, I get errors:

$ ls
ls: cannot access 'mobile-rec': Structure needs cleaning
ls: cannot access 'camera': Structure needs cleaning
total 12
d????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? mobile-rec
d????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? camera
drwx------ 2 root root 12288 Jul  1 16:40 lost+found

I unmount it and fsck /dev/sda1
(Way too many errors to paste here), inodes removed...clear yes
Warning, had trouble writing out superblocks.

$ fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.29.2
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

also # tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 reports it found a DOS partition.

After much testing like above, I come to the conclusion the hardware is rewriting the beginning of the partition, no matter where I put it, (I did try adding partitions to buffer the beginning sector.)
Thus erasing the superblock 0 with ... a dos partition?
$ fsck -b 8193
does not recover the lost files. It may write the correct superblock, but it gets lost right away.

I get the same results in Debian and Raspbian-buster.

Question: Are some SSD firmware hard coded for DOS only?

Any workarounds?
I don't think complaining to the chinese sellers will be enough if all their current products that look like cheap copies, are programmed to do this. Other people will run into this also.

Thank you

Comment: I had a similar problem with an external ssd via usb3 as well as with an m.2 ssd via usb 3. My problem happened with ext4, exfat and ntfs although it happens LESS with ext4. When my problem occurs, a shutdown and restart fixes it but only that- no remount, etc. I also don’t write to the drive much, just read now that I’ve managed to get everything on it I need. I kind of think there’s a problem with the usb3 implementation on the RP, but idk. But I don’t think the problem is that some ssd firmwares are hard coded for dos only; I don’t think that’s a thing. You never know, though

Comment: Why would you disable journaling? It is there for a reason!

Comment: I have 3 Pi4's that use SSD as primary (actually only) drive and never had any issue with them - I use cheap SSD (Silicon Power) and cheap adapters (UGreen) and have done so since USB boot was available in `stable` firmware. So, what brand/model is the SSD, what brand/model is the USB3 to Sata cable/enclosure/whatever you use.

Comment: FYI @Milliways - I used to disable journaling on some SDCards on some of my older pi's - because I used cheap SDcards and the resulting responsiveness improvements are noticeable :p I now use quality SD cards on those pi's

Comment: @RonKyle Because the seller said "the hard disk is only compatible with exfat format"

Comment: @Milliways I like journaling, but for SSD I read this will reduce the write cycles.

Comment: @Bravo idVendor=048d, idProduct=1234 Product: Disk 2.0 Manufacturer: USB If you search ebay, these 2 case shapes are the most prevelant, one 2.5" looks like a copy of Samsung, and the other is shaped like a M2 card. They both have the same Vendor Product number. They come with the enclosure and USB3 cable.

Comment: that vendor/product is a thumb drive - I thought you said you had an SSD drive

Comment: @Bravo Except it has a cord, is larger than a thumb, and larger than 256GB. It is marketed as a SSD, although I'll agree that may be questionable, as it fails a few tests for that definition... it is not SATA, and does not appear to be robust or fast. I've asked other ebay sellers of the same product if it can be reformatted, 3 have replied, No. Exfat only. Now I wonder what the Argon One M2 has for specs that might make it special.

Comment: @StewartAndreason Haha, really? So now is the seller just an idiot, or is there something to it? Other sellers say the same thing, too?  Did you see the Chipsbank UMPTool for the CBM2099? I don't know if I can link to it here but it was pretty easy to find w/google. Looks like it could be helpful.   Also, I have the Argon One M2 and I don't think that it IS anything special, specs wise. M.2 over USB3.

Comment: @RonKyle After reformatting back to EXFAT, and doing incremental writes and comparing the checksums... I can now say these 4 drives in 2 designs with all the same vendorID, they are fakes. The capacity is only around 32GB and then existing files get overwrited. There are dozens of ebay sellers with the same pictures and descriptions. I'll let you imagine how many are fakes. Thanks all.

Comment: @Bravo notify: my last comment to Ron, ditto for you. It is neither SSD or thumb drive.

Comment: @tlfong01 Please jump in this thread: After looking into other SSD for sale, I become convinced all the cheaper priced ones are all Exfat only, and any attempt to repartition them, only result in breaking to the point they freeze and don't work. I see you have tested SSD, but only mention Exfat in the preparation. Can anyone answer my first question, which brand model SSD work with ext4?